# Mocked service throws nullPointerException

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, junit4

I'm pretty new to java, trying write some unit test for my code. But stuck on one of them.

this is method i want test :

```
public Reservation findSpecificReservation(Long id) throws NullPointerException{
    Reservation reservation = null;
    Optional<Reservation> byId = iReservationRepository.findById(id);
    if(byId.isPresent()){
        reservation = byId.get();
    }
    return reservation;
}
```

those are variables mock and setup :

```
private IReservationService iReservationService;

@Mock
private IReservationRepository repository;


@Before
public void setUp() {
    initMocks(this);
    iReservationService = new ReservationServices(repository);
}
```

and test looks like :

```
    @Test
public void shouldFindReservation() {
    Long id = 1L;

    Reservation expected = getDefaultReservation();

    when(iReservationService.findSpecificReservation(id)).thenReturn(getDefaultReservation());

    Reservation actual = iReservationService.findSpecificReservation(id);

    Assert.assertThat(expected, is(actual));
}
```

My test throws nullpointer exception in the lane where im trying do when thenReturn, ireservationService.findSpecificReservatin(id) throws it.

Can someone please let me know what im doing wrong ?

Im begginer in programming and will be glad if you can go soft on me Thanks !

edit adding whole classes :

```
package com.hotelReservation.hotelReservation.services;

import com.hotelReservation.hotelReservation.domain.ReservationStatusResponse;
import com.hotelReservation.hotelReservation.entity.Reservation;
import com.hotelReservation.hotelReservation.entity.User;
import com.hotelReservation.hotelReservation.repository.IReservationRepository;
import com.hotelReservation.hotelReservation.repository.IRoomRepository;
import com.hotelReservation.hotelReservation.repository.IUserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class ReservationServices implements IReservationService {

private IReservationRepository iReservationRepository;
private IRoomRepository iRoomRepository;
private IUserRepository iUserRepository;

@Autowired
public ReservationServices(IReservationRepository iReservationRepository) {
    this.iReservationRepository = iReservationRepository;
    this.iRoomRepository = iRoomRepository;
    this.iUserRepository = iUserRepository;
}

@Override
public ReservationStatusResponse addReservation(LocalDate begin, LocalDate end, Long roomId, Long userId, String breakfast, String diner, String rentCar, int adultsForReservation) {
    PriceCounter priceCounter = new PriceCounter();
    int days = 0;
    if (end.isAfter(begin)) {
        days = begin.until(end).getDays();
    }
    int price = priceCounter.calculatePrice(breakfast, diner, rentCar, days, adultsForReservation);
    Reservation newReservation = Reservation.builder()
            .begin(begin)
            .end(end)
            .roomForReservation(iRoomRepository.findById(roomId).get())
            .user(iUserRepository.findById(userId).get())
            .breakfast(breakfast)
            .dinner(diner)
            .rentCar(rentCar)
            .adultsForReservation(adultsForReservation)
            .price(price)
            .build();

    ReservationStatusResponse reservationStatusResponse = checkIsReservationDatesAreNotTaken(newReservation.getRoomForReservation()
            .getId(), newReservation.getBegin(), newReservation.getEnd());
    if (reservationStatusResponse.isPossible()) {
        iReservationRepository.save(newReservation);
    }
    return reservationStatusResponse;
}

@Override
public void cancelReservation(Long id) {
    iReservationRepository.deleteById(id);
}

public List<Reservation> findAllReservationOfSpecificUser(Long id) {
    List<Reservation> allByUserId = iReservationRepository.findAllByUserId(id);
    return new ArrayList<>(allByUserId);
}

public Reservation findSpecificReservation(Long id) throws NullPointerException {
    Reservation reservation = null;
    Optional<Reservation> byId = iReservationRepository.findById(id);
    if (byId.isPresent()) {
        reservation = byId.get();
    }
    return reservation;
}

public List<Reservation> findAllReservationsOnRoom(Long roomId) {
    return iReservationRepository.findReservationsByRoom(roomId);
}

@Override
public ReservationStatusResponse checkIsReservationDatesAreNotTaken(Long roomId, LocalDate begin, LocalDate end) {
    ReservationStatusResponse reservationStatusResponse = new ReservationStatusResponse();
    if (begin.isAfter(end) || begin.isBefore(LocalDate.now())) {
        reservationStatusResponse.setPossible(false);
        reservationStatusResponse.setReason("Begin date is after end date or before today !");
        return reservationStatusResponse;
    }
    int newReservationPeriod = begin.until(end).getDays();
    List<LocalDate> newReservationDates = new ArrayList<>();
    List<LocalDate> takenReservationDates = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= newReservationPeriod; i++) {
        newReservationDates.add(begin.plusDays(i));
    }
    List<Reservation> allReservationsOnRoom = findAllReservationsOnRoom(roomId);
    for (Reservation r :
            allReservationsOnRoom) {
        int existingReservationPeriod = r.getBegin().until(r.getEnd()).getDays();
        for (int i = 0; i <= existingReservationPeriod; i++) {
            takenReservationDates.add(r.getBegin().plusDays(i));
        }
        for (LocalDate l :
                takenReservationDates) {
            for (LocalDate lo :
                    newReservationDates) {
                if (l.isEqual(lo)) {
                    reservationStatusResponse.setReason("Date is taken");
                    reservationStatusResponse.setPossible(false);
                    return reservationStatusResponse;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    reservationStatusResponse.setPossible(true);
    reservationStatusResponse.setReason("Possible");
    return reservationStatusResponse;
}


@Override
public List<Reservation> findAll() {
    return iReservationRepository.findAll();
}


}
```

test class :

```
package com.hotelReservation.hotelReservation.services;

import com.hotelReservation.hotelReservation.domain.ReservationStatusResponse;
import com.hotelReservation.hotelReservation.entity.Reservation;
import com.hotelReservation.hotelReservation.entity.Room;
import com.hotelReservation.hotelReservation.repository.IReservationRepository;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks;

public class ReservationServicesTest {

private IReservationService iReservationService;

@Mock
private IReservationRepository repository;


@Before
public void setUp() {
    initMocks(this);
    iReservationService = new ReservationServices(repository);
}

@Test
public void ShouldDeleteReservationById() {

    Long id = 12L;

    Mockito.doNothing().when(repository).deleteById(id);

    iReservationService.cancelReservation(id);

    Mockito.verify(repository, Mockito.times(1)).deleteById(id);
}

@Test
public void shouldFindReservation() {
    Long id = 1L;

    Reservation expected = getDefaultReservation();

    when(iReservationService.findSpecificReservation(id)).thenReturn(getDefaultReservation());

    Reservation actual = iReservationService.findSpecificReservation(id);

    Assert.assertThat(expected, is(actual));
}

@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void shouldThrowNullPointerExceptionOnFindingReservationWithDoesntExist() {
    Long id = 1L;

  iReservationService.findSpecificReservation(id);

}

@Test
public void shouldReturnListOfReservations() {
    Long id = 1L;
    List<Reservation> reservationListFromDb = getReservationDatesListFromDb();

    when(iReservationService.findAllReservationsOnRoom(id)).thenReturn(reservationListFromDb);

    List<Reservation> actual = iReservationService.findAllReservationsOnRoom(id);

    Assert.assertArrayEquals(reservationListFromDb.toArray(), actual.toArray());
}


private List<Reservation> getReservationDatesListFromDb() {
    Reservation first = Reservation.builder()
            .begin(LocalDate.of(2018, 05, 01))
            .end(LocalDate.of(2018, 05, 03))
            .build();
    Reservation second = Reservation.builder()
            .begin(LocalDate.of(2017, 05, 01))
            .end(LocalDate.of(2017, 05, 03))
            .build();
    return Arrays.asList(first, second);
}


private Reservation getDefaultReservation() {
    return Reservation.builder()
            .begin(LocalDate.of(2018, 7, 23))
            .end(LocalDate.of(2018, 7, 29))
            .reservationId(1234L)
            .roomForReservation(getDefaultRoom())
            .rentCar("NO")
            .breakfast("NO")
            .dinner("NO")
            .adultsForReservation(2)
            .build();
}

public Room getDefaultRoom() {
    return Room.builder()
            .howManyPeople(2)
            .id(12L)
            .roomClass("Hobbit")
            .build();
}
}
```

Comment: @lucumt because that's the proper way to inject a mock dependency in a unit test

Comment: Why are you trying to use Mockito to tell what the **service**, which you are testing, should return? You should use Mockito to tell what the **dependency of the service**, i.e. the repository, should return. Also, your wole method can be replaced by `return iReservationRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);`

Comment: There's no point in comparing expected/actual values (that's integration tests) when you are mocking repository.

Comment: @CrazySabbath that's nonsense. The contract of the method, which is tested in isolation, is to return what the repository returns. The test verifies the contract. Nothing is wrong with that.

Comment: @Michal Can you add full classes instead of just methods?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `@InjectMocks` over `iReservationService`.

```
@InjectMocks
private IReservationService iReservationService;
```

**Also** there's no need for doing

```
iReservationService = new ReservationServices(repository);
```

in your `setup()` method.

**And** you should be mocking the calls of `repository` and not the `iReservationService` itself.